# Were the Lestranges particularly rich?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, in final chapters, there’s a discussion between Voldemort and Lucius Malfoy that specially draws my attention:

> ‘The Lestranges should stand here,’ said Voldemort quietly. ‘But they are entombed in Azkaban. They were faithful. They went to Azkaban rather than renounce me … **when Azkaban is broken open, the Lestranges will be honoured beyond their dreams**.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Chapter 33: *The Death Eaters*.</sub>

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* we know that the Lestrange’s family Vault is filled with valuable goods:

> The door of the vault melted away to reveal a cavelike opening crammed from floor to ceiling with golden coins and goblets, silver armour, the skins of strange creatures — some with long spines, others with drooping wings — potions in jeweled flasks, and a skull still wearing a crown.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 26: *Gringotts*.</sub>

It is clearly stated in the [canon](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Purebloods) that the Lestrange family is pureblood, and so is the Black family (let’s not forget that Bellatrix was née Black). I do not have any canon quote in which to base this, but I recall that pureblood families such as the Malfoys, Lestranges, and Blacks were reasonably wealthy (at least in some point of the Houses’ history).

**Is there any canon indication that Voldemort fulfilled his promise and made Rodolphus and Bellatrix considerably richer after they broke away from Azkaban? Were they particularly rich even before they were imprisoned<sup>1</sup> ?**

I realise I might just be misinterpreting “honoured” in a monetary way. But I don’t recall them being *specially highly ranked* in Voldemort’s followers lines<sup>2</sup> (at least not Rodolphus); **it seems logically to me that Voldemort is talking about wealth/status.**

---

<sup>1: It’s worth noting that Gringotts do not seem to care about wizards being in prison, as Sirius is indirectly able to access his vault when he was a fugitive in the *Prisoner of Azkaban*.</sup>

<sup>2: One could argue that (in Voldemort’s mind) Voldemort’s army is comprised by: a) Voldemort, b) replaceable pawns.</sup>

Comment: You're missing a 3rd option: they are "honoured" by him telling them "attagirl". A sign of approval from El Voldy is surely a big honour in his mind.

Comment: @DVK "_beyond their dreams_"... I know Voldemort is a sociopath, but that would be evil even for himself :P

Comment: Another option #4: they would be granted "more power" - Voldemort clearly intends to institute a totalitarian regime, and those typically have pecking hierarchy below the tyrant. Lestranges may have been meant to be intended to be "top lapdogs"

Comment: What promise ? Moreover Death Eaters are not mercenaries.

Comment: @StephaneMathis have you read the question?

Comment: Yes, they will be 'honoured'. It doesn't sound like a promise. Furthermore, Voldemort and Bellatrix do not care about money at all.    I guess Bellatrix as a part of an ancien pure blood family must be really rich, like the Black and Malfoys (Weasley doesn't count, family is too big = inheritance to share in many pieces and too many children to support)

Comment: @StephaneMathis I would gladly accept a well founded answer even if it states that my whole interpretation is wrong. I may just jumped to conclusions too quickly.

Comment: Now that *Cursed Child* is out, we know how the Lestranges were honored....

Comment: @Adamant yeah. Actually that'd be a good example of how the Lestranges were (kinda) held in with regard by Voldy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bellatrix Lestrange was certainly honored beyond her wildest dreams: She had the honor of *[Spoilers for TCC]*

> Bearing Voldemort's child for him. There could be almost no other honor as great as that for someone like her.

This is in addition to what's mentioned in TDH, that Voldemort

> placed a *part of his soul* in their Gringotts vault.

So both of them had

> the cup in the vault;

and Bellatrix had

> Delphini Riddle.

Comment: Technically that was all in-universe speculation. It was never confirmed, and Rowling [refused to answer](https://youtu.be/O9aiVAFEsrg?t=70) when directly asked to confirm it last week.

Comment: @ibid What's speculating? That that's how they were honored?

Comment: That Delphi was Voldemort's child.

Comment: @ibid I seem to remember it *specifically* mentioning that in TCC.... But my Kindle is broken, so I can't check, but...

Comment: All that was said in TCC child is that Delphi led to believe that. It's never made clear whether it was what actuality happened.

Comment: Still, until proven wrong, Delphi being a Riddle is canon. All things considered, it seems that Voldemort did put his trust in the Lestranges, which is quite the thing for a sociopath. Great answer.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández *... put his thrust in the Lestranges ...*

Answer (score -2):

All the Pure blood families are rich, except Weasley's for their overpopulation. The other pure blood families don't even respect the Weasley's as a pure blood, because of their economic status and Arthur Weasley's raids against wizarding families.

> “Ron gave a slight cough, which might have been hiding a snigger. Draco Malfoy looked at him.
>
> “Think my name’s funny, do you? 
>   No need to ask who you are. My father told me all the Weasleys have red hair, freckles, and more children than they can afford.”
>
> He turned back to Harry. “You’ll soon find out some wizarding families are much better than others, Potter. You don’t want to go making friends with the wrong sort. I can help you there.”
>
> -Harry Potter and The Sorcerers Stone, Chapter 6-Journey From Platform 9¾

The Lestranges riches were shown in their Gringotts Bank vault, whose phrase was already attached in question. They have (or had) too much gold for their family.

To the Question phrase "Were they particularly rich" is a good point to notice. They are not the only rich ones in Magical World. Even the Black family (Pure-blooded) are also rich. Sirius Black sent Harry a Fire Bolt as a gift, which Harry can only buy by giving all the gold in his Gringotts vault.

The power which Voldemort mentioned to provide Bellatrix  as well as other Lestranges was definitely  not in terms of money, it may be in terms of power. It should be noted that, during the second Wizarding war, the Lestranges were treated slightly above than that of Malfoy's by the Dark Lord for the very reason of them not denouncing him. It may also be one of the reason why the Dark Lord didn't take Bellatrix wand but preferred to Lucius Malfoy ([More about this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90798/why-did-voldemort-take-the-wand-of-one-of-his-most-loyal-servants/90800#90800))

Comment: -1. "All the pure blood families are rich" there is no evidence to back that up

Comment: The Lovegood and Gaunt families are both pure blood and not wealthy.